# Rename MYSQL column names for php select element

Tags: php, mysql, html, select, preg-replace

Hi I'm constructing a html select element like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<select name="column" class="column">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row[0] == 'id' || $row[0] == 'tstamp' || $row[0] == 'boiler2oil')
              continue;
        echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".ucwords($row[0])."</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

The way i've named the columns in the table is rather ugly, with underscores, etc...how can i rename them so i can change the select element display (value can stay the same) changes to something a bit more readable and visually pleasing. Is this possible? Would it be some sort of preg_match/preg_replace?

Comment: What is the goal of this task? If you want to show **column names,** show them **as is**. If you want fancy titles - don't take field names then, but write all titles in the **template**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to rename them to.  Do you want to do something simple like remove underscores?  Is there a rule you can use to clean them all up?

If not, why not add a hash with entries that map from the name in the table to the name you want to print out for the drop-down list?

```
# map from column name to display name
$labels = array(
    'col1' => 'Column 1',
    ...
);

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
echo '<select name="column" class="column">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row[0] == 'id' || $row[0] == 'tstamp' || $row[0] == 'boiler2oil')
          continue;

    # use a more friendly name if one has been defined above in $labels
    if(array_key_exists($row[0], $labels))
          $label = $labels[$row[0]];
    else
          $label = $row[0];

    echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$label."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Also note that you really should be using `htmlentities`, e.g. `echo "<option value='".htmlentities($row[0])."'>".htmlentities($label)."</option>";`

Comment: I think either would be fine, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It can probably done with `str_replace` alone, which is more efficient than `preg_replace` for simple things like this.

Comment: Oh ok, would i have to know what the str_replace is targeting or is it a general function?

Comment: This should give you enough to work with:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array which will be having columnName as "key" and Name to Display as "value". Then Echo element of this array rather than displaying column name.